# how can I split matrix into training testing data whilst ensuring there is at least one value present in the rows and columns of the training matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, train-test-split

I want to randomly split a sparse matrix into training and testing data of the same dimensions whilst ensuring there are no columns or rows full of zeros in the training set.

For my algorithms to work i need at least one value in each row and column for the training set.

I have tried to use this library function: 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

For example given the matrix:

```
[[0, 1, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[8, 0, 0, 1]]
```

The matrix could be split to produce this training matrix:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 8]]
```

where the second row contains only 0's. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold 
import numpy as np 

# Create some dummy data
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 0])

# Remove rows having all of their columns equal to 0
X = X[~np.all(X == 0, axis=1)]

# Assuming 2-fold cross-validation
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
kf.get_n_splits(X)
```

Now `kf` has two training/testing folds:

```
for training, testing in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[training], X[testing]

    # Do whatever you want with your model ...

    print(“Training:”, training, “Testing:”, testing)


>>> ('Training:', array([2, 3]), 'Testing:', array([0, 1]))
>>> ('Training:', array([0, 1]), 'Testing:', array([2, 3]))
```

Comment: Great thank you, last question, if i were to increase the splits, how would i define more training samples?

Comment: @SophiaBouchama In cross validation you generate multiple folds of training and testing instances. You can’t have more training than testing folds. If you want to increase the folds then change n_splits paramter when instantiating KFold

Comment: I am still getting matrices with rows and columns that only have 0's present, is there a way to ensure there is at least one value per row/column in the training and testing samples?

Comment: @SophiaBouchama Can you please edit your question and include some sample data?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: @SophiaBouchama Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to get rid of the row, I want to keep the same dimensions but ensure that when the the matrix is split, the training sample does not have row of 0's or column of 0's.

Comment: @SophiaBouchama So what do you want to do with these rows if you don’t want to discard them? I don’t think that your requirements make sense to be honest.